# RDLC Report works fine for local users;doesn't work elsewhere

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc, temp

App built with VS (WPF and C#). Added RDLC report. Users here have no problem displaying report. Elsewhere error is: 'Set connectionID threw an exception', 'Line number '7' and line position '14'.
The users that are not local have no problems running the app, just the report. The same user with the same login can come here and run the report, but go there and they get the error. 
I have full admin rights/superuser. I go there, use a computer and get the error. I took a laptop from here to there and it displayed the report. I then disconnected the laptop from the wireless and used the same ether cord that the computer that would not display the report used and the report ran fine. Changed the timeout to 60 secs. No difference.
Believe it may be where the temp file is writing, but can't find the temp file.
Any thoughts?
Thanks very much

Comment: Well asked and all your steps sanity check of regular user vs admin remote vs local, etc.  The line 7 Pos 14, might that be in the .RDLC file give you (via XML viewing, not designer mode) some indication as to what it may be attempting to connect to?  Just a thought.

Comment: I thought that was a great suggestion, but I can't find it. Did a search on "rdlc" for the entire folder. Other than what I already have visible, I looked through the .csproj file and found nothing helpful.

Comment: ... if it helps, the line 7 on the report viewer is "using System.Text" and on the report, it's "using System.WindowsControls". The report viewer xaml is "xmlns:rv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms"" and the report xaml is the Title, height and width

Comment: Can't answer my own question due to reputation, but here's the answer:Found it ... needed to install the ReportViewer.msi over there. We had installed it here, but never done it there.
Thanks to all